# Последовательности

Tags: c

Перечислить все последовательности нулей и единиц длины `N` `(N<=100)`, в которых никакие две единицы не стоят рядом. Можно как-то модифицировать этот код?

```
int main(){
    int arr[]={1, 2, 3};
    for(int i = 0; i< (1 << sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)); i++){
        int k = i, j = 0;
        while(k){
            if (k & 1) printf("%i ",arr[j]);
            j++;
            k >> =1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Эта программа печатает все подмножества массива `arr`.

Comment: а вы представляете количество таких последовательностей? Это как бы 100 число фибоначи примерно.

Comment: @pavel Да, представляю

Comment: ну тогда как минимум битовый сдвиг вызовет переполнение... Ответ на конкретный вопрос - да можно

Comment: А при чем здесь вообще этот код? Почему вы решили, что они имеет хоть какое-то отношение к вашей задаче?

Comment: @AnT Подумал, что она похожа на задачу с подмножествами

Comment: @pavel, что-то ты перестарался с оценкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy странно. Я так рассуждал. У нас есть какой-то набор цифр слева. Мы можем или поставить 1 потом 0 или просто поставить 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если рассматривать последовательное инкрементирование двоичного числа из `N` битов начиная с нулевой комбинации `0..0`, то последовательности с двумя соседними единичными битами будут возникать в процессе инкрементирования в виде `xxx110..0`, т.е. пара соседних единиц, за которыми следуют нули.

Понятно, что сколько бы мы ни инкрементировали такую последовательность, она нас не будет интересовать (т.е. будет содержать эту пару соседних единиц), пока мы не получим перенос в младшую единицу этой пары. То есть нас заведомо не интересуют никакие результаты инкремента, пока мы не дойдем до последовательности `xxx111..1` и не прибавим к ней единицу, получив `xxx000..0`. Это ненужные результаты не надо генерировать вообще - их несложно "перепрыгнуть" в процессе генерации последовательностей.

Таким образом, для генерации искомых последовательностей нам надо реализовать обычный инкремент `N`-значного двоичного числа с одной хитрой модификацией: если какой-то разряд `i` в результате инкремента получил значение `1`, то нам надо проверить следующий старший разряд `i + 1`. Если он тоже содержит `1`, то мы должны искусственно продолжить выполнение алгоритма инкрементирования с разряда `i`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 5u

bool increment_no_11(unsigned char (*n)[N])
{
  unsigned i;   

  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    if ((*n)[i] == 1)
      (*n)[i] = 0;
    else if (i + 1 == N || (*n)[i + 1] == 0)
    {
      (*n)[i] = 1;
      break;
    }

  return i < N;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char n[N] = { 0 };

  do
  {
    for (unsigned i = N; i-- > 0;)
      printf("%d", n[i]);
    printf("\n");
  } while (increment_no_11(&n));
}
```

Для `N = 100` количество последовательностей будет равно `927372692193078999176`.

Answer (score 1):

Схематично:

```
proc variants(current) {
    if current.length = 100 {
        output current;
    }
    else
    {
        call variants(current + '0');
        if current[current.length] = '0' {
            call variants(current + '1');
        }
    }
}

call variants('');
```